# How this Knockout code is working

Tags: knockout.js

got confusion when get the below code.i am trying to understand how knockout works.
here is the full code

```
<span data-bind="text: TimeString">Start...</span>
var vm = {
            TimeDT: ko.observable(),
            TimeString: ko.observable()
        };

        function updateValues() {
            var data = new Date();
            vm.TimeDT(data);
            vm.TimeString(data);
        }

        ko.applyBindings(vm);

        updateValues();
        setInterval(updateValues, 5000);
```

have look at this code

```
 var vm = {
                TimeDT: ko.observable(),
                TimeString: ko.observable()
            };
```

i can understand a object is declare like this way. vm is object here and it has two function called **TimeDT & TimeString** but i could not understand this

```
TimeDT: ko.observable(), what is the meaning of 
ko.observable() is assign to TimeDT ?

what will store in TimeDT return by  ko.observable() ?
```

please expalin in details with few more sample code. thanks

Comment: It is explained pretty well in the knockoutjs documentation - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ko.observable` is how knockout keeps track of changing variables. If you want knockout to be able to respond to a change, you must use `ko.observable`.

So, if you do this:

```
var myVM = {
    someProp = true
}
```

And then somewhere else in your code you do this:

```
myVM.someProp = false;
```

Knockout won't see the change. However, if you do this:

```
var myVM = {
    someProp = ko.observable(true);
}
```

Then you can change it's value later with:

```
myVM.someProp(false);
```

and Knockout will notice the change and update any bound html automatically.

Note: Since `ko.obsevable` is a function rather than an actual property (thank IE for not supporting Javascript getters and setters), accessing the value is a little different:

```
var whatsMyValue = myVM.someProp();
```

You have to actually call the method and it will return it's value. It's easy to forget that when you first start and end up doing something like this:

```
if (myVM.someProp) {
    // this code will always be executed regardless of the actual value 
    // of someProp() because myVM.someProp is a function, 
    // which is truthy.
}
```

What you actually need is

```
if (myVM.someProp()) {
    // now this works as expected.
}
```

Also note, when you do this:

```
TimeDT: ko.observable()
```

`TimeDT` is an observable with no initial value. But then you do this:

```
vm.TimeDT(data);
```

Knockout will see the change and update any bindings to `TimeDT`.

Comment: here u gave ko.observable(true); but in my code ko.observable(); has no true or false.....so default is true ? what will occur if i pass false? thanks for answer.

Comment: @Thomas: If you don't give it a value, it'll be undefined (which is falsey) by default. Of course, `ko.observable` can hold things other than just bools!

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#observables): `special JavaScript objects that can notify subscribers about changes, and can automatically detect dependencies`.

That code initializes the `TimeDT` property as an observable which will track changes to it's value and update the UI if necessary.